# Sql request error syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Hey guys my question is really simple : i had this request :

```
->prepare("SELECT
    CONCAT(YEAR(`p`.`created_account`), '-', MONTH(`p`.`created_account`)) AS `month` 
    FROM
   `profile` AS `p` 
    GROUP BY
    YEAR(`p`.`created_account`), MONTH(`p`.`created_account`)");
```

I was in mysql 5 and that works but i upgrade to mysql 8 and know i have this error :

> object(Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException)#707 (8) { ["driverException":"Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException":private]=> object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException)#766 (10) { ["errorCode":"Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException":private]=> int(1064) ["sqlState":"Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException":private]=> string(5) "42000" ["message":protected]=> string(282) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `profile` AS `p` GROUP BY YEAR(`p`.`created_account`), MONTH(`p`.`created_a' at line 1" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> string(5) "42000" ["file":protected]=> string(92)

If that can help i have that one that works in both version :

```
->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`p`.`id`) AS `total` FROM `profile` AS `p` GROUP BY YEAR(`p`.`created_account`), MONTH(`p`.`created_account`)");
```

And when i remove the group by that works but not grouped by :/ so i have :

> array(9) { [0]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-6" } [1]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-6" } [2]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-7" } [3]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-8" } [4]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-8" } [5]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-8" } [6]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-8" } [7]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-8" } [8]=> array(1) { ["month"]=> string(6) "2018-8" } }

So what should i do for not repeat same month ? thx for all that will try to answer :p

Comment: Count your `()`.

Comment: same error when i count

Comment: It's not an issue with the syntax - at least not according to: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: Is this a result of the *ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY* setting in MySQL

Comment: i vardump it  (the result)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing a close brace for `CONCAT()`
Can you try :

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(`p`.`created_account`), '-', MONTH(`p`.`created_account`)) AS `month` FROM `profile` AS `p` GROUP BY YEAR(`p`.`created_account`), MONTH(`p`.`created_account`)
```

Comment: i forget to put it in the post sorry but that's not working ... same error

Comment: like if i change the version that's working but not on mysql 8

Comment: Hmm . Weird. I use v8 and The only change i had to make was to change the `GROUP BY` clause.  ` SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(`p`.`date_joined`), '-', MONTH(`p`.`date_joined`)) AS `month` FROM `users` AS `p` GROUP BY date_joined;`

Comment: really strange because i change the version and that works and change it again for 8.0 and don't works

Comment: when i remove the group by that works but not grouped :/ like i have 2018-08 2018-08 2018-09 2018-10 2018-10

Comment: what should i do for not repeat the same caracters

Comment: @LuisRosario, Have you tried `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_account, '%Y-%m') as month from profile GROUP BY month  `; ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found just do like this for who has the same problem : (seems like the v8 of mysql does not allow the group by YEAR or MONTH so just do :)

```
->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(YEAR(`p`.`created_account`), '-', MONTH(`p`.`created_account`)) AS `month` FROM `profile` AS `p` GROUP BY (`created_account`)");
```